# Read words in a specific order

Tags: java, string, cpu-word

I use the JAVA.

The type of word to read is String.
I want to read words in a certain order.

for example
[image]

Here I want to read only numbers. I do not want to read the number on the far left. It's just a list. Meaningful numbers for me are 6,3,5,5.

After all, I want to add all of these numbers.

I need help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your attempts.

Comment: Is this input a single _string_, or is it a snapshot of an input text _file_ ?

Comment: can you explain more your example?

Comment: where is the Java code?! You have to try something in advance. And searching for "CSV(TSV) reader in Java" was not possible for you?

Answer (score 0):

In case the format above is in correct order then below code would give you result

```
    String[] lineSplit  = str.split("\n"); // Split content of each line
    int value = 0;
    for(String line : lineSplit) {
        String [] textSplit = line.split(" ");  // Split line text into words by space
        value += Integer.valueOf(textSplit[2]);  // add the value to the value 
    }
    System.out.println(value);
```